# List<Model> null when passing it to nested Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Not sure why the list is null when I have added the model to it after setting all the data from network call.

If I use finalHourList the data shows in the log if I print to logcat. I can't use finalHourList as I have tied it to the HourlyForcast model inside the adapter also. So, I can't pass the adapter a string and have to pass it a `List<HourlyForcast>`. Not sure why `finalHourList.add(forecast);` is null after I have set data to forecast.

The hardcoded list works with no issues, but now I am trying to populate the RecyclerView with the data coming back from the network call.

```
public class HomeRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<String> dates;
    private Context context;
    private String defaultZipcode = "55372";
    private String mEnglishTemp, mCivilTime, mCondtion, mConditionIcon;
    private List<HourlyForcast> finalHourlyList = new ArrayList<>();
    HourlyForcastAdapter adapter;
    private HourlyForcast forecast;

    public HomeRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<String> dates) {
        this.dates = dates;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.hourly_cardview, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Typeface titleStyle = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                "font/Roboto-Medium.ttf");
        holder.mDate.setTypeface(titleStyle);
        holder.mDate.setText(dates.get(position));

        getHourlyWeather(defaultZipcode);

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 4);
        holder.mInnerRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        holder.mInnerRecycler.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        adapter = new HourlyForcastAdapter(context, finalHourlyList);
        holder.mInnerRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dates.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mDate;
        private RecyclerView mInnerRecycler;

        ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
            mInnerRecycler = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.hourlyRecycler);
        }
    }

    private List<HourlyForcast> getAllItemList() {

        List<HourlyForcast> allHours = new ArrayList<>();
        allHours.add(new HourlyForcast("4:00 PM", "8°", "Overcast"));
        allHours.add(new HourlyForcast("5:00 PM", "6°", "Sunny"));
        allHours.add(new HourlyForcast("6:00 PM", "5°", "Sunny"));
        allHours.add(new HourlyForcast("7:00 PM", "3°", "Rainy"));
        allHours.add(new HourlyForcast("8:00 PM", "3°", "Sunny"));
        allHours.add(new HourlyForcast("9:00 PM", "3°", "Snowing"));
        allHours.add(new HourlyForcast("10:00 PM", "4°", "Sunny"));
        allHours.add(new HourlyForcast("11:00 PM", "60°", "Sunny"));
        return allHours;
    }

    public void getHourlyWeather(String zipCode) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(context.getString
                (R.string.hourlyForcastURL)).newBuilder();
        urlBuilder.addPathSegment(zipCode + ".json");
        String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                call.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                String mResponse = response.body().string();
                try {
                    JSONObject hourlyObject = new JSONObject(mResponse);
                    JSONArray hourForcastArray = hourlyObject.getJSONArray("hourly_forecast");
                    for (int i = 0; i < hourForcastArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject HourlyObject = hourForcastArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject mTemp = HourlyObject.getJSONObject("temp");
                        mConditionIcon = HourlyObject.getString("icon_url");
                        mEnglishTemp = mTemp.getString("english");
                        mCondtion = HourlyObject.getString("condition");
                        JSONObject FCTRemoveal = HourlyObject.getJSONObject("FCTTIME");
                        mCivilTime = FCTRemoveal.getString("civil");

                        forecast = new HourlyForcast();
                        forecast.setTime(mCivilTime);
                        forecast.setCondition(mCondtion);
                        forecast.setDegrees(mEnglishTemp);

                        /*finalHourlyList = new ArrayList<>();
                        finalHourlyList.add(mEnglishTemp);
                        finalHourlyList.add(mCivilTime);
                        finalHourlyList.add(mCondtion);*/

                        finalHourlyList = new ArrayList<>();
                        finalHourlyList.add(forecast);
                        Log.i("HOURLYLIST", finalHourlyList.toString());
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Adapter I am passing the list to

```
public class HourlyForcastAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HourlyForcastAdapter.HourlyViewHolder> {
    private List<HourlyForcast> itemList;
    private Context context;

    public HourlyForcastAdapter(Context context, List<HourlyForcast> itemList) {
        this.itemList = itemList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public HourlyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.hourly_single, parent, false);
        return new HourlyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(HourlyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Typeface regStyle = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                "font/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
        holder.mTimeText.setTypeface(regStyle);
        holder.mDegreeText.setTypeface(regStyle);
        holder.mTimeText.setText(itemList.get(position).getTime());
        holder.mDegreeText.setText(itemList.get(position).getDegrees());
        holder.mWeatherIcon.setText(itemList.get(position).getCondition());
     //   holder.mWeatherIcon.setImageResource(itemList.get(position).getImageID());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return itemList.size();
    }

    public static class HourlyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView mTimeText, mDegreeText, mWeatherIcon;
      //  ImageView mWeatherIcon;

        public HourlyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTimeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.timePlaceHolder);
            mDegreeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.degreePlaceHolder);
            mWeatherIcon = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.weatherIconHolder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you consider using obervables?

Comment: @Caspain Not sure what that is and looking into it now, but not sure how that helps with the list being null inside the onResponse method of the network call.

Comment: one of the reason it is null, is because there is a race condition to read and wait for the result from the network request and then setting the data.

Comment: @Caspain If I add them to that commented out finalHourlyList and print to the console the values are in there but I can't pass that as its a string and not tied to the model. What do you mean race condition?

Comment: @Caspain That last code change you suggests with calling the recyclerview with .adapter.notifyDataSetChange isnt able to happen as you cant call the adapter on the recyclerview like that.

Comment: Then consider declaring array of adapters, then get the index for a certain adapter then call the update notifier.

Comment: Why would I create multiple adapters for 1 recyclerView when I just want to display the response from the network call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having the network call inside an adapter,place it in the class where you call the HomeRecyclerAdapter say MainActivity. And pass the List in the Constructor of HomeRecyclerAdapter.

In MainActivity

- final   RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new HomeRecyclerAdapter(days,finalHourlyList);
- getHourlyWeather(String zipCode)

In HomeRecyclerAdapter

```
public HomeRecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<String> dates,ArrayList<HourlyForcast> finalHourlyList) {
    this.dates = dates;
    this.finalHourlyList = finalHourlyList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

alright figured i out, this is what happens.

```
HourlyForcastAdapter adapter = new HourlyForcastAdapter(context, finalHourlyList); //passing this list to adapter
```

that line of passes a null reference with no data currently in it. Therefore you initially something empty therefore you get something empty. To remedy this, add a method in the next adapter class, that accepts a finalHourlyList. Then when the network call is finished manually call this method thus passing the newly updated list.

Also in the next adapter, call notifyDataSetChange to signal a refresh.

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Make sense?
The main reason is because recycler eagerly displays data when a adapter is attached.but there is no data, so it freaks out.

change `private List<HourlyForcast> finalHourlyList;` to

```
private List<HourlyForcast> finalHourlyList = new ArrayList<>();
```

at the very top.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 forecast = new HourlyForcast();
                    forecast.setTime(mCivilTime);
                    forecast.setCondition(mCondtion);
                    forecast.setDegrees(mEnglishTemp);

                    /*finalHourlyList = new ArrayList<>();
                    finalHourlyList.add(mEnglishTemp);
                    finalHourlyList.add(mCivilTime);
                    finalHourlyList.add(mCondtion);*/

                    finalHourlyList = new ArrayList<>();
                    finalHourlyList.add(forecast);
```

this line below will work,becuase it is currently populated with data. but what i am saying is this, when you call this line in onBind `adapter = new HourlyForcastAdapter(context, finalHourlyList);` there is no data yet. what you are thinking is this, becuase i set the data before any changes i make will automatically reflect,but no it wont. You have to trigger a update and let the recycler view know there is new content available.So you need to update the inner recycler view adapter.like this. model this logic.

```
       holder.mInnerRecycler. adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: still not sure what im suppose to do, trying to figure it out from what you posted. Ive posted both Adapters but not really sure what to put in the new method inside the HourlyForcastAdapter to pass it back to the HomeRecyclerAdapter

Comment: Well, it doesn't crash and I do not get null anymore. But the data isn't showing either.  Am I passing it wrong to the list or parsing it wrong? I have updated my HomeRecyclerAdapter to show my changes.

Comment: i already told , it is empty when u call it, the network does occur, but the recycler view is already set, manually update the content using notifyDataSetChange

Comment: so add adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after creating the finalHourlyList inside HomeRecyclerAdapter? You said to use it in the next adapter which would be the HourlyForcastAdapter but I am never creating an adapter inside that adapter.

Comment: I added the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but it isn't updated the adapter. When I place a log into the second adapter it has the data. Not sure where to place the adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to get it to actually update with the data not the hard coded list. I tried making the adapter public static from HomeRecyclerAdapter to call it inside HourlyForcastAdapter and that didnt work either.

Comment: I understand what your saying, but I am unable to actually place holder.mInnerRecycler. adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); anywhere in the adapter as you can not set .adapter to the mInnerRecycler. So I am not sure how to actually update the nested adapter from the web service when .notifyDataSetChanged() isn't working inside the network call or before/after the adapter is set.

Comment: because every item in the main recycler as a recycler view right?

Comment: yes the cardview within the main recyclerview has a recyclerview

Comment: that means every child from that recycler has it's own adapter.

Comment: holder.mInnerRecycler.setAdapter(adapter); this needs to be array of recycler views

Comment: your implementations needs to be re modeled.

Comment: So i need to change the code for adapter to be an array of recycler views? If so do you have any links showing that as I am not seeing anything for an array of recycler views when Googling it.

Comment: tell you what, give me some time. I will rewrite it and send a gist. its a lot of changes. probably later i am at work.

Comment: the concept of nesting recycler is complicated by nature.

Comment: Yes it is, I have never done anything like this before. Thank you